# Agda - Building proofs interactively - How to use the hole syntax?

Tags: agda, agda-mode

Sorry for the strange title, I have no idea how these concepts are actually named.

I'm following an `Agda` tutorial and there's a section explaining how to build proofs inductively: https://plfa.github.io/Induction/#building-proofs-interactively

It's pretty cool that you can expand your proof step by step and have the hole (this `{ }0`) update its contents to tell you what's going on. However, it is only explained how to do that when using the `rewrite` syntax.

How does this work when I want to "manually" do the proof within a `begin` block, for example:

```
+-assoc : ∀ (m n p : ℕ) → (m + n) + p ≡ m + (n + p)
+-assoc zero n p =
  begin
    (zero + n) + p
    ≡⟨⟩ n + p
    ≡⟨⟩ zero + (n + p)
  ∎
+-assoc (suc m) n p =
  begin
    (suc m + n) + p
    ≡⟨⟩ suc (m + n) + p
    ≡⟨⟩ suc ((m + n) + p)
    ≡⟨ cong suc (+-assoc m n p) ⟩
      suc (m + (n + p))
    ≡⟨⟩ suc m + (n + p)
  ∎
```

The problem is the following. Let's start with the proposition and start of the evidence:

```
+-assoc : ∀ (m n p : ℕ) → (m + n) + p ≡ m + (n + p)
+-assoc m n p = ?
```

This evaluates to:

```
+-assoc : ∀ (m n p : ℕ) → (m + n) + p ≡ m + (n + p)
+-assoc m n p = { }0
```

In this case, I want to do a proof by induction, so I split these using `C-c C-c` using the variable `m`:

```
+-assoc : ∀ (m n p : ℕ) → (m + n) + p ≡ m + (n + p)
+-assoc zero n p = { }0
+-assoc (suc m) n p = { }1
```

The base case is trivial and is replaced with `refl` after resolving it using `C-c C-r`. However, the inductive case (hole 1) needs some work. How can I turn this `{ }1` hole into the following structure to do the proof:

```
begin
  -- my proof
  ∎
```

My editor (spacemacs) says `{ }1` is read-only. I cannot delete it, only insert stuff between the braces. I can force-delete it but that's clearly not intended.

What are you supposed to do to expand the hole into a `begin` block? Something like this

```
{ begin }1
```

does not work and leads to an error message

Thanks!

EDIT:

Okay, so the following seems to work:

```
{ begin ? }1
```

This turns it into this:

```
+-assoc : ∀ (m n p : ℕ) → (m + n) + p ≡ m + (n + p)
+-assoc zero n p = refl
+-assoc (suc m) n p = begin { }0
```

That's a progress :D. But now I can't figure out where to put the actual steps of the proof:

```
...
+-assoc (suc m) n p = begin (suc m + n) + p { }0
-- or
+-assoc (suc m) n p = begin { (suc m + n) + p }0
```

Neither seems to be working

Comment: I'm using spacemacs. I type in insert mode (using vim mode)

Comment: "`{ }1` is read-only" -- are you by any chance typing in the insert/overwrite mode? Typing in a hole is supposed to work indeed. You should type something like `{begin ? ∎}`, hit `C-c C-SPC` and that will reify the code.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear about this: I can type stuff in between { and }, just the braces themselves are read-only. And writing { begin ? }1 actually does work (only without the \qed). It turns the text into `begin { }1` which is progress :D But how do I continue? I can't figure out where to put the first step

Comment: I updated the question with the current state

Comment: You should always fill a hole with an expression whose type is equal to the goal. `(suc m + n) + p` is a natural number, which is not the goal. Try to put `(suc m + n) + p ≡⟨⟩ ?` inside the hole.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you very much, now it's working as intended! Do you want to put your two comments as an answer? Then I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `{ }1` is read-only

This message is shown in two cases:

- you're trying to delete a hole with backspace, which is not going to work. You can use C-backspace, though, if the hole is empty
- you're trying to edit an empty hole in the insert/overwrite mode, which is also not going to work

A rule of thumb is that you always refine a hole with `C-c C-SPC` with an expression of the type that is equal to the goal. In your case this means starting with `begin ?`, then giving `(suc m + n) + p ≡⟨⟩ ?` and so on.

There are two ways to refine a hole:

- `C-c C-r`: creates new holes for you when given a function. E.g. with this setup:

  ```
  test : Bool
  test = {!!}
  ```

  if you type `not` in the hole

  ```
  test : Bool
  test = {!not!}
  ```

  and refine, you'll get

  ```
  test : Bool
  test = not {!!}
  ```

  i.e. the new hole is created automatically for the argument.

  With this way or refining a hole Agda also reformats your code the way it prefers, which I don't like, so I usually don't use it.
- `C-c C-SPC`: doesn't create new holes for arguments and doesn't reformat your code

Comment: Hey, if you don't mind: I'm a little bit further in the book (https://plfa.github.io/Relations/#transitivity) and for the transitivity proof of ≤ it is suggested to use emacs interactivity again. But I have no idea how to do that using holes again. What do I have to type? All I got working is `≤-trans = ?`, which turns into `≤-turns = {  }0`. I would greatly appreciate your help :)